# Unexpected output from all.equal.POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct

I'm getting unexpected output from the all.equal method in R, specifically the implementation for POSIXct, all.equal.POSIXct.

```
t <- Sys.time()
isTRUE(all.equal(t, t+1))
```

returns TRUE, and

```
isTRUE(all.equal(t, t+1, scale = 1))
```

returns FALSE.

However, if you look at the definition of all.equal.POSIXct, you can see that the scale parameter has a default of 1:

```
> all.equal.POSIXct
function (target, current, ..., scale = 1) 
{
    check_tzones(target, current)
    NextMethod("all.equal")
}
<bytecode: 0x22eac90>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

You get the same results if you explicitly call all.equal.POSIXct instead of all.equal.

Why isn't the default parameter scale = 1 being picked up in the first call to all.equal.POSIXct?  Am I doing something wrong, or have I fundamentally misunderstood something, or is this a bug?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is a great question. Both answers below suggest it might be a bug, so I have filed a bug report at https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=14969

Comment: Cool, thanks for submitting the bug report! I was just about to do the same!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm going out on a slight limb here, but I think you have discovered a bug.

Here is my suggested fix:

```
all.equal.POSIXct <- function (target, current, ..., scale = 1) {
  check_tzones(target, current)
  NextMethod("all.equal", scale=scale, ...)
}
```

Then the function gives the correct results:

```
all.equal(t, t+1)
[1] "Mean scaled difference: 1"

all.equal(t, t+1, scale=10)
[1] "Mean scaled difference: 0.1"
```

---

This is why the existing code doesn't work:

The definition for `all.equal` is:

```
all.equal <- function (target, current, ...) UseMethod("all.equal")
```

- Notice that there are three arguments: `target`, `current` and `...`.
- Thus, whenever you use `NextMethod` these three arguments will be passed to the next method.
- However, in the case of `all.equal.POSIXct` there is an additional argument `scale=`, but this doesn't get passed on either implicitly or explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

Looks like a bug.  I'm not an expert on method dispatch, but a quick reading of `?NextMethod` suggests `scale=scale` needs to be added to the `NextMethod` call in `all.equal.POSIXct`:

```
all.equal.POSIXct <-
function (target, current, ..., scale = 1) 
{
    check_tzones(target, current)
    NextMethod("all.equal", scale=scale)
}
```